Concatenation of Excel Files with Python
I have a lot excel files, all with the same format and I just want to make one big file with the concatenation of all the others.
For the moment I tried to use pandas in a simple for loop with only two files and it worked correctly but in my final file the data from my two files are separated by an empty row and I can't understand why.
import pandas as pd
import glob as glob

listExcel=glob.glob("/content/*.xlsx")

AllData=pd.DataFrame()
for f in listExcel:
  df=pd.read_excel(f)
  AllData=pd.concat([AllData,df])


AllData.to_excel("AllData.xlsx")

I tried to check size of my files with df.shape and AllData.shape and here it also seems correct AllData size is exactly the size of the two concatenated files. I'm a panda beginner and I can't understand where this empty line is coming from...
EDIT:
After all your comments, I checked my input excel files but there are no blank line, empty row or empty files in my data input (I just tried with two small files for the moment)
The empty line in the concatenated file is exactly between the first file end and the start of the second one.
All the excel files have the same format with a first row for the name of the columns, this first row is identical in each of my input files and this is the one replaced by an empty row. Is this a part of the solution?

There is nothing in your code which would generate an empty row. You need to look carefully at the input data.

Your code works fine for me too. There is a blank line in your input Excel file I would say.

... or an empty Excel file in your /content/ folder perhaps? Are you on Windows or Mac?

There is certainly a blank line in your input.

Where is the empty line in relation to the Excel files data?

Before concatenating try dropping the empty rows (i.e., rows that are empty or have no data for all columns).
You can use
 df.dropna(axis = 0, how = 'all')
 AllData=pd.concat([AllData,df])

You can also try dropping the empty row(s) before writing your AllData df into an excel file so that you avoid writing any empty rows:
AllData.dropna(axis = 0, how = 'all')

You can refer this link for more explanation:
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/58890/delete-drop-only-the-rows-which-has-all-values-as-nan-in-pandas
